# trying to rotate 28BYJ48 and 2 NEMA17 stepper motors simultaneously but the rpi reboots each time

Tags: python, pi-2, rpi.gpio

I am trying to control a 28BYJ48 stepper(Driver ULN2003AN) and 2 stepper motors NEMA17(A4998). I wrote the code using python using PIGPIO but the rpi turns off every time I try to run the code.

I tried to run the code without the 2 NEMA steppr motor and only the 28BYJ48 motor(with the same code) eventhen  it turnsoff. All the motors are provided external power Rpi used to only give control signals.

I wrote a code to control the 28BYJ48 motor individually it works fine.

The problem arises when I try all the motors. Please help me sort out the problem .Is there any restiction on number of GPIO pins that can be used simulatneously.

Comment: A likely explanation is the motors are drawing power from the Pi which causes a voltage drop and reboot.  You need to add clear photos of your wiring.

Comment: I will add the photos asap.I am connecting all control wires of the stepper motors including mode wires of the A4998 driver to the Rpi.